# Change CSS of div with jquery on a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click

I need a help regarding a click function.

In starting I need to show few class with different div classname inside a main div class which can be ID.
Now on click of a anchor I will grab that classname and leaving that all other class inside that main div need to be visible.
All classes will start with a unique name like marker_automobile, marker_sample-class, etc.

Now on click of marker_automobile, the marker_sample-class, etc need to be hide and only marker_automobile need to be shown. Now on click of marker_sample-class, all other classes expect this should be hide.

Sorry for my bad english.

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YL2pj/)

```
<a href="#" class="changer" data="data1">Data1</a>
<a href="#" class="changer" data="data2">Data2</a>
<a href="#" class="changer" data="data3">Data3</a>

<div id="content">
  <div class="data1">
    content 1
  </div>
  <div class="data1">
    content 2
  </div>
  <div class="data2">
    content 3
  </div>
  <div class="data3">
    content 4
  </div>
  <div class="data1">
    content 5
  </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".changer").click(function() {
       var data = $(this).attr("data");
       $("."+data).css( "display", "none" );
    });

});
```

Comment: That's not the most elegant solution, but it worked here. Or I didn't understand what you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make all `div` elements visible again when button is clicked. Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(".changer").click(function() {
       $("div[class^=data]").show(); //show all divs
       var data = $(this).attr("data");
       $("div[class^=data]").not("."+data).css("display","none");//hide button 
       related ones
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/YL2pj/3/)**

Comment: HI Actually what I need to do is to hide the other classes and show the one which is clicked. :(

Comment: Yes, worked. Can you tell me a way in which I can again show all the class again on click of ALL.

Comment: Just use this `$("div[class^=data]").show();` to show all.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you are not making all `div` elements visible again when the button is clicked for consecutive times. Also, `data` is not a valid attribute. In my example I changed your HTML to use a `data-*` attribute. Try this:

```
<a href="#" class="changer" data-rel="data1">Data1</a>
<a href="#" class="changer" data-rel="data2">Data2</a>
<a href="#" class="changer" data-rel="data3">Data3</a>
```

```js
$(".changer").click(function () {
    $('#content div').show(); // show all elements again
    $("." + $(this).data('rel')).hide(); // hide the related ones only
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YL2pj/1/)

Comment: HI
Actually what I need to do is to hide the other classes and show the one which is clicked. :(

Comment: In that case just swap over `hide()` and `show()` in my above example.

Comment: Yes, worked. Can you tell me a way in which I can again show all the class again on click of ALL.